# How do I change upload_max_filesize and max_execution_time in php.ini?

Tags: php

I am trying to change my upload_max_filesize and max_execution_time in my php.ini

I've tried

```
upload_max_filesize = 80M
max_execution_time = 300
```

and

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '45')
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '80M')
```

I ran phpinfo and none of them changed...what gives?

thanks,
J

Comment: Are you running phpinfo() from your command line or through a web server or what? It matters.

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver?

Comment: Is this hosted locally or on a hosted server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to restart the server before you check the `phpinfo()`

Comment: @user1193385 restart the **web server**

Comment: You need to get access to the server via SSH so that you can restart the web server from the command prompt...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to restart the computer/server after making a php change such as this. You could make the changes directly to the php.ini and not reboot.

You'll likely need to have your provider allow this, or set it in an .htaccess file.